# Mapping CSV data into new structure

Tags: javascript, csv, object, d3.js

I have a csv which contains the following data

```
this_year   |   minus_one_year  |   minus_two_year  |   minus_three_year
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           |   2               |   2               |   3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
4           |   5               |   5               |   5
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2           |   2               |   2               |   2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
4           |   5               |   4               |   4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           |   2               |   3               |   3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I read this csv file and now I need to organise the data.  My end goal is to have the following output

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "name": "1",
      "node": "this_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "2",
      "node": "this_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "4",
      "node": "this_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "2",
      "node": "minus_one_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "5",
      "node": "minus_one_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "2",
      "node": "minus_two_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "3",
      "node": "minus_two_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "4",
      "node": "minus_two_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "5",
      "node": "minus_two_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "2",
      "node": "minus_three_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "3",
      "node": "minus_three_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "4",
      "node": "minus_three_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "5",
      "node": "minus_three_year"
    }
  ]
}
```

So for each column, I am getting the unique values.  So this_year has 3 nodes, because the data contains 3 unique values, 1, 2, and 4.

I am using D3 but at the moment this is only involved with the parsing.  For the formatting of data, I think I am on the right track, I am using map.

So far I have something like this

```
let graph = {"nodes" : [], "links" : []};

graph.nodes = output.map(function(d) { return [
  {
    'name': d.current_month,
    'node': d.value
  }
]; });

console.log(graph.nodes)
```

Where output is the csv data.  Obviously this is not working, but getting a bit confused by all this mapping and reducing etc.  So with the data I have, how can I achieve the 
above output?

I have included a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3me0o2zn/4/) to demonstrate what I have done so far.

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

```
 d3.csv('churn_status.csv')
    .then(function(data) {

        vm.graph.nodes = data.reduce(function(acc, line){
            return acc.concat(Object.entries(line).map(function(column){
                return {name: column[0], node: column[1]}
            }))}, []);


        vm.graph.nodes = vm.graph.nodes.sort(function(a,b) { return a.name > b.name ? -1 : 1});
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        // handle error
    });
```

Comment: have you looked at the output: ALL is UNDEFINED

Comment: it's undefined because it's accessing keys `d.current_month` and `d.value` that doesn't exist. Do you want to groups by unique values? or just make the nodes as your example?

Comment: Hi, it would be unique for each column, so that it ends up like my output.  Sorry, current_month was supposed to be this_year, was playing about with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do that, you have to break the lines into key / value using `Object.entries()`, then push your new objects to nodes.

Note `Object.entries({a:100})` returns an array `["a", 100]`

```
let graph = {"nodes" : [], "links" : []};

output.forEach(function(line) { 
    Object.entries(line).forEach(function(column){
      graph.nodes.push({
         'name': column[0],
         'node': column[1]
      })
  })
})
console.log(graph.nodes)
```

Edit: you can also use the reduce function that works in similar way

```
output.reduce(function(acc, line){
    return acc.concat(Object.entries(line).map(function(column){
        return {name: column[0], node: column[1]}
    }))}, [])
```

Comment: This appears to give a very strange output, not like the output I was after e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/6vy5w3hp/

Comment: yes, it works when you use `d3.csvParse(data)`  not with `d3.csvParseRows(data)` those are two different methods.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I see now.  To through another spanner in the works, I was just showing an example because I couldnt get a csv online.  Really, I am using `d3.csv('some.csv') ` does that make a difference?  Also, is it possible to order this by the columns, so all this_year ones come first etc?

Comment: yes, you can just sort your graph.nodes `graph.nodes.sort(function(a,b) { return a.name > b.name? -1 : 1})` and if is the same with `d3.csv()` put your code inside the function `d3.csv('some.csv', function(output) { //here is your code  })`

Comment: Sorry, got a bit lost on where to put the sort function?  Would this be outside the loop?

Comment: once you've processed the nodes, you can re-assign it `graph.nodes = graph.nodes.sort(function(a,b) { return a.name > b.name? -1 : 1})`

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my post to show what I have.  Currently however, would both solutions, it now sorts the data, but it is showing all of the duplicates.  Are there any way to remove these?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Row 1 within your csv are the titles. This has to be repeated in the node object to suit your model. You could achieve this by looping through the titles and then parsing the rest of the csv file:

```
var d3 = require("d3");
let data = "this_year,minus_one_year,minus_two_year,minus_three_year\n1,2,2,3\n4,5,5,5\n2,2,2,2\n4,5,4,4\n1,2,3,3";

let output = d3.csvParseRows(data);
let nodeTitles = output[0];
let graph = {"nodes" : []};

console.log(nodeTitles);

for (var i = 0; i < nodeTitles.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < output.length; j++)
    {
        var obj = {name:output[j][i], node:nodeTitles[i]}; 
        if (!graph.nodes.some(function(element) {
            return (element.name == output[j][i]) && (element.node == nodeTitles[i]);
          }))
        {
            graph.nodes.push(obj);
        }
    }
}
console.log(graph);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tested it and it works well.  Only problem is that it duplicates values for each column.  So year_1 should only have 3 nodes (1, 2 and 4), currently it has 5 e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/91xrbq6h/

Comment: @kate_hudson, I have edited to only add unique items to the final array

Comment: Many thanks.  Random question, I have just found out that `csvParseRows` returns an array as it assumes there is no header.  In my real code, I am not reading in a string, but a real csv file, therefore using d3's `csv` function which parses things as an object.  When I apply this code to that, it obviously doesnt work.  Do you know what I would need to do to get it working with an object?  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

map function parameter d has no property "current_month" and "value". And your SCV also has no fields with this name.